# Hitting time of a maximum of random walk converges to that of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, brownian-motion, random-walk

Suppose $S_n$ is a simple random walk; formally, $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for $X_i\sim\mathcal{U}(-1,1)$, i.i.d.. Denote by $M_n$ the maximum of the random walk on $n$ steps; formally, $M_n=\max_{0\le k\le n}S_k$. Finally, let $T_n$ be that maximum's hitting time; formally, $T_n=\min\{k,\ 0\le k\le n:\ S_k=M_n\}$.

We may have dual notations for the standard Brownian motion $B(t)$ on the interval $0\le t\le 1$: $M$ is the maximum of the motion (formally, $M=\max_{0\le t\le 1}B(t)$), and $T$ is the hitting time of $M$ (formally, $T=\min\{t,\ 0\le t\le 1:\ B(t)=M\}$).

I know that at least in some sense, the random walk $S_n$ converges to the Brownian motion $B(t)$. Here's a way to formalize this: if $S(t)$ is the linear interpolation of $S_n$; that is
$$S(t)=S_{\lfloor t\rfloor}+(t-\lfloor t\rfloor)(S_{\lfloor t\rfloor + 1} - S_{\lfloor t\rfloor}),$$
and $S_n^*(t) = S(nt)/\sqrt{n}$ then $S_n^*$ converges in distribution to $B(t)$ (on the interval $[0,1]$).

My question is as follows: does it follow from the above convergence, or true for any other reason, that $T_n/n$ converges in distribution to $T$?

Comment: Yes it does, and to see why, you simply must make precise what is meant by the assertion that $S_n^*$ converges in distribution to $B$. Can you do that?

Comment: It means that if a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and uniformly continuous, then $\mathbb{E}\left(f(S_n^*)\right)\to\mathbb{E}\left(f(B)\right)$ in probability.

Comment: "Uniformly continuous" for which distance?

Comment: @Did - for the supremum metrics on $C[0,1]$, say. Does it matter?

Comment: Usually, convergence in distribution corresponds to the convergence of $E(F(S_n^*))$ to $E(F(B))$ (simple convergence, not convergence "in probability", which is absurd since these are just numbers) for every continuous function $F$ (not only for the bounded continuous ones). The problem here is that the functional $F:g\mapsto\min\{t\mid g(t)=\max g\}$ is not continuous at those $g$ such that $\{t\mid g(t)=\max g\}$ is not a singleton. Fortunately, $\{t\mid B(t)=M\}$ is a singleton, almost surely, hence I guess the argument carries through nevertheless.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, I'll give it another thought.